# Three.js How to create a simple 3d Point

Tags: three.js

I want to create some simple 3D points. 
Is there any way to create this geometry without tricks?
- I don't need a pointcloud ( or do I need ? )
- I don't want a sprite ( I don't want to load any image).
Maybe I'm some clumsy but I don't see the way. 
Any idea & advise ? Thanks.

Comment: The question is what you would like to do with the 3D points. Your question is way too general.

Comment: @gaitat. I want simply send a simple 3d point to my scene. I know how to create cloudpoints ans sprites, but in this case I only want to send 1 or 2 points every time.  Thanks.

Comment: `new THREE.Vector3 (posX, posY, posZ)`

Comment: I did a double take on your question too. You are not explaining your problem very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to use a simple sphere geometry with a small radius for your project.

```
  var pointGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 16, 16 ), // adjust the first value for the 'point' radius
      pointMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),  // adjust the color of your 'point'
      point3D = new THREE.Mesh( pointGeometry, pointMaterial );

  scene.add( point3D );
```

Important side notice: the radius of the sphere and the size it takes on your screen depends on the distance from the camera and the `camera.['far']` value, you set while initiating.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have tried that... Finally I'm going to create some kind of pointcloud because I need a 1x1 sprite size.